# Subprocess check_output returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

This is my python code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output("ls",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

import subprocess
subprocess.check_output("yum",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

The first `.check_output()` works well, but the second returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/pythonconsole/console.py", line 378, in __run
r = eval(command, self.namespace, self.namespace)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 616, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'yum' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Why does this happen? Is it because `ls` is the original shell command but `yum` is the new package? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The command `yum` that you launch was executed properly. It returns a non zero status which means that an error occured during the processing of the command. You probably want to add some argument to your `yum` command to fix that.

Your code could show this error this way:

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_output("dir /f",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
```

Comment: so if i just want to implement command (g3-from-scratch.csh tpall.fna from-scratch) in python. This command will create some files in current directory but give not reply in console, i test this command in shell,it work. how could i implement it in python?originally,i use os.system(),but it just return (sh: 1: g3-from-scratch.csh: not found)

Comment: I try your code for yum, it work well, but not for g3-from-scratch.csh. I do not what is the different with them, I can use they directly in console.

Comment: why would you use `check_output()` if you are not using the captured output?

Comment: finally， i solve the problem, i should add abs path in front of g3-from-scratch.csh, because my environment path is relative path (~/software/glimmer3.02) but it should write (/home/username/software/glimmer3.02).

Comment: Downvote: This is a clumsy workaround. Don't call `check_output()` if you don't actually want Python to check the exit code and raise an error if it's not zero. See [jfs' anser elsewhere on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928363/874188) for details and a better approach.

Comment: I'm not sure if I like the solution. This (the try/except) assumes the return state of the command, when not zero, to be an erroneous situation. That's by fare not always the case. I just want the return value (or the std output) and 'if not zero' we'll do something else. My point is a nonzero return might be a valid situation still. Liked the other answer better.

Answer (score 25):

The word `check_` in the name means that if the command (the shell in this case that returns the exit status of the last command (`yum` in this case)) returns non-zero status then it raises `CalledProcessError` exception. It is by design. If the command that you want to run may return non-zero status on success then either catch this exception or don't use `check_` methods. You could use `subprocess.call` in your case because you are ignoring the captured output, e.g.:

```
import subprocess

rc = subprocess.call(['grep', 'pattern', 'file'],
                     stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
if rc == 0: # found
   ...
elif rc == 1: # not found
   ...
elif rc > 1: # error
   ...
```

You don't need `shell=True` to run the commands from your question.

Comment: So you check the return code after the `subprocess.call` anyway. Is there a real case where you should use `call` instead of `check_output` apart from the scenario of command that has invalid return code? Thx!

Comment: Exceptions should be raised in exceptional cases only (there are exceptions but the general rule holds). If you expect `grep` to return `1` (if it is not an error in your application) then you should not raise the exception. The exit status is checked to find out whether the pattern is found in the file: it is the whole point of running the child process in the first place. Also, you should not use `check_output()` unless you use its return value (the output from the subprocess)

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I understand the idea with `grep` but it is still not that obvious for me. I just created a question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27938050/882697 . Could you have a look? Thank you again!

Comment: Since quite some time back, the primary interface is `subprocess.run` which gives you more fine-grained control by way of its `check=True` keyword argument; omit it to run without checking the result (but understand the implications).

Comment: @tripleee it is unfortunate that `check` is not true but default in run() (errors shouldn't go unnoticed in general). `call()` provides a simpler interface then `run()` but you probably would need run() someday anyway so it is worth learning it.  It didn't exist at the time of the answer.